# Setting dimensions of layers in a convolutional neural network

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch

Say I have 3x100x100 images in batches of 4 as input and I'm trying to make my first convolutional neural networks with pytorch. I'm really not sure if I'm getting convolutional neural networks right because when I train my input through the following arrangement I run into the error:

`Expected input batch_size (1) to match target batch_size (4).`

**The following is my forward nnet:**

Then If I were to pass it through:

```
nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 5)
```

I would get 6 layers of maps each with dimensions (100-5+1).

Then If I were to pass it through:

```
nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
```

I would get 6 layers of maps each with dimensions (96/2)

Then if I were to pass it through:

```
nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
```

I would get 16 layers of maps each with dimensions (48-5+1)

Then If I were to pass it through:

```
self.fc1 = nn.Linear(44*44*16, 120)
```

I would get 120 neurons

Then If I were to pass it through:

```
self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
```

I would get 84 neurons

Then If I were to pass it through:

```
self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 3)
```

I would get 3 outputs which would be perfect because I have 3 classes of labels. But as I said before, this leads to an error which is really surprising because this makes a lot of sense to me.

Full neural network code:

```
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F


class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 5)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(44*44*16, 120)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 3)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = x.view(-1, 16 *44*44)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x


net = Net()
net.to(device)
```

Comment: Can you tell the output of `x.shape`? (shape of the input tensor)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is correct and very detailed.

However, you have used two pooling layers (see relevant code below). So output after the second step will be 16 maps with `44/2=22` dimension.

```
x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
```

To fix this either not pool or change the dimension of the fully-connected layer to `22*22*16`.

To fix by not pooling modify you forward function as below.

```
def forward(self, x):
    x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
    x = F.relu(self.conv2(x))
    x = x.view(-1, 16 *44*44)
    x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
    x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
    x = self.fc3(x)
    return x
```

To fix by changing the dimension of the fully-connected layer, change the declaration of networks as below.

```
def __init__(self):
    super(Net, self).__init__()
    self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 5)
    self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
    self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(22*22*16, 120)
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
    self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 10)
```